# DotNetNuke: Why doesn't "Remember me" work like I expect?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

Running the latest version of DotNetNuke, version 5.6.1 and cannot find a good answer to why Username and Password cannot be remembered on a DotNetNuke site.  [This thread](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/1704/Why-doesnt-Remember-me-work-like-I-expect.aspx) goes on about cookies but really misses the point.  User 'ptleitch' puts it best when he askes:

*"Well thats all fine and dandy. You learn something new everyday. The problem is, my users are submitting issues along the lines of they expect the "remember login" feature to auto-populate the "username" field in the login control, and I've got nothing to tell them other than they're out of luck."*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, to enable the functionality, as orka said, you'll want to set the PersistentCookieTimeout in the web.config to something greater than 0 (value is in minutes).

In addition to that though, I'd suggest altering the verbiage presented to the user on the login screen to be more accurate. "Remember Login" does make it seem like it's just going to auto-populate your credentials - which, functionality-wise, doesn't really make sense.

So, I'd recommend changing "Remember Login" to "Stay signed in."

You access (and update) the verbiage through the DNN user interface by browsing to Admin -> Languages -> (edit English static resources for site link) -> Local Resources -> DesktopModules -> Admin -> Authentication -> App_LocalResources -> Login.ascx.

On a little bit of a tangent - I'd go as far as to suggest that you should change everything from "Login" to "Sign in" as well (e.g. User Sign In, Stay signed in, etc) - just because it makes more sense.

Answer (score 10):

The [short answer](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/1784/a-new-solution-to-an-old-problem.aspx) of [long story](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/1704/Why-doesnt-Remember-me-work-like-I-expect.aspx) is using `PersistentCookieTimeout` parameter at the `appSettings` section of `web.config` file. The parameter value is in minutes and should be set bigger than 0 (20160 for two weeks) to work `RememberMe` functionality properly.

Answer (score 1):

I would add that many websites remember the username only.  They autopopulate the username, and the user must enter the password.  This is the functionality that many users expect.  I don't know of a way to do it with DNN.  As mentioned above, the "Remember Me" function is really "Stay Signed In" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers here and I agree it should read "Stay signed in".  One tip along these lines: For my DNN 7+ installs, I found the Language override here:

Admin -> Languages -> (edit English static resources for site link) -> Local Resources -> DesktopModules -> **AuthenticationServices -> DNN -> App_LocalResources -> Login.ascx**

This is because I use the standard authentication services (DNN).  If you utilize other authentication providers, you may find the text to override lives in a different folder at the same level as the DNN folder.